# Creating a helper system in laravel is correct or not?

Tags: laravel, class, controller, routes, helper

My helper root
app\http\myHelpers\customClass.php

customClass.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\myHelper;

class CustomClass {

    public static function customFunction(){
        return 'Custom class working......';
    }
}
```

Controller function

```
public function test(){
        CustomClass::customFunction();
    }
```

routes

```
Route::get('/test', 'HomeController@test');
```

There is no need composer command. It is work properly but I am not sure to is it correct system or wrong system. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

How you organize your code is honestly a personal choice. So there is nothing wrong with your code. You don’t need any composer command because in Laravel everything in the app folder is auto loaded by composer: [The App Directory](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/structure#the-app-directory)

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly fine, what you can do additionally is to organize function inside traits and place them e.g. in the /app folder.

```
<?php

namespace App;

trait HasRoles
{
  public function hasPermission(Permission $permission)
    {
        return $this->hasRole($permission->roles);
    }
}
```

and use this trait inside your controller like

```
use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, HasRoles;
```

just another way of bundling helper functions!